# How to use *arg & **kwarg in __init__()

Tags: python-3.x, initialization, parameter-passing

For a class I have I would like to set default values for attributes if their values are not passed in during instantiation. Currently what I'm doing is this:

```
class MyClass():
   def __init__(self, attrA=None, attrB=None, ...)
   ...
```

Is this the pythonic way to do it? Can I use *arg or **kwarg here and set default values for attributes that are not passed in during instantiation so that

```
myobj = MyClass()
```

sets `attrA = None, attrb = None`

```
myobj  = MyClas(attrA = <somevalue>)
```

sets `attrA = <some value> and attrB = None, attrC = None` and so on

I also have setter methods that will allow me to update an attribute after instatiation, if needed.

Comment: Using `*args` and `**kwargs**` has the disadvantage that the valid arguments become hidden in the signature. You'll have to document clearly then what is supported. The advantage is the gained flexibility in the way you can process them.

As an example, in `matplotlib` almost every method has many supported `**kwargs**`, with some of them passed on to other  functions internally for different subtasks. 

So generally I'd say it depends on the amount of supported arguments you have. If it's just a small bunch, I'd write them out.

Comment: "the disadvantage that the valid arguments become hidden in the signature." - could you please elaborate, with an example?